# how to change a list to a specific string.

Tags: python

```
class Bag:
    def __init__(self, i=None):
        self.bag = []
        if i == None:
            pass  # i is None, do nothing after create empty bag
        elif type(i)==list:
            self.bag.extend(i) # append whole list i into bag with extend method
        else:
            self.bag.append(i) # append single item i into bag 

    def __repr__(self):
        for s in self.bag :
            return s

    def __str__(self):
        for s in self.bag :
            return s
```

In the __str__method. It supposed to return a string.

The list is Bag(['a', 'c', 'b', 'b', 'd', 'd', 'd']). And

```
__str__ is supposed to return Bag(a[1], c[1], b[2], d[3])
```

Can anyone tell me how to make it work? Many thanks.

Comment: Both of your for loops will return the first s and then stop.

Comment: rather than `type(i) == list`, you're better off with `isinstance(i, list)` or even `isinstance(i, collections.Iterable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `collections.Counter` here to help:

```
def __str__(self):
    counts = Counter(self.bag)
    count_str = ','.join('{}[{}]'.format(k, v) for k, v in counts.items())
    return 'Bag({})'.format(count_str)
```

The great thing about this is that the counter does all the work of figuring out how many of each item are in your `bag`.  All the rest of it is just formatting details.  One downside is that the counter is not ordered.  If you want an order, you could use the `.most_common` method (which will order the counts from most common to least-common), or you could use something like an [ordered unique recipe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-in-whilst-preserving-order) to figure out how you want to iterate over the counter.

Comment: Using a Counter defeats the purpose of implementing a bag (bag = Counter). He should be using a dictionary to store the item from the beginning.

Comment: @AdamVanProoyen -- It's true that `Counter` makes a really nice `Bag` (and it's intended too).  It's a bit unclear to me how OP is going to use the above code, but it might just be algorithms practice and he/she wants some quick `str`/`repr` to check while debugging or something ...